# django floppyforms BaseGMapWidget - default-zoom and lat/long

Tags: django, forms, gis

Does someone know a simple way to set the default zoom and latitude/longitude with *floppyforms.gis.BaseGMapWidget* ? And additionally, when creating an entry set panning as default tool.

In the form i define:

```
class PointWidget(floppyforms.gis.PointWidget, floppyforms.gis.BaseGMapWidget):
    map_width = 690
    map_height = 300

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        widgets = {
            'coordinates': PointWidget(),
        }
```

This perfectly shows the map widget and i can set a point. It also nicely centers & zooms the point when loading the form for an existing entry.
But when displaying the form to create a new entry it centers at the west-cost of africa..

Is there a way to achieve this (preferably by defining in the form/widget-class and not using additional javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, override `get_context_data()` on your widget class and point it
to a custom template:

```
class PointWidget(floppyforms.gis.BaseGMapWidget, floppyforms.gis.PointWidget):
   template_name = 'custom_lonlat.html'
   default_lon = 'something'
   default_lat = 'something'

   def get_context_data(self):
       ctx = super(PointWidget, self).get_context_data()
       ctx.update({
           'lon': self.default_lon,
           'lat': self.default_lat,
       })
       return ctx
```

Then create the `custom_lonlat.html` template:

```
{% extends "floppyforms/gis/google.html" %}

{% block options %}{{ block.super }}
options['default_lon'] = {{ lon }};
options['default_lat'] = {{ lat }};
{% endblock %}
```

If you want to make the default lon/lat dynamic, you can set them directly on the form instance from your views code:

```
form = EventForm()
form.fields['coordinates'].widget.default_lon = 'something'
form.fields['coordinates'].widget.default_lat = 'something else'
```

I'm the author of floppyforms and I've seen this question a couple of times… I'll add this answer to the official docs soon.

Comment: Works perfectly! Now I also know how to easily use the js options! Thanks a lot for answering and also for dloppyforms!